# How to get Lat, Long from DynamoDB close to userLocation ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-dynamodb

In my application I am using Google API for nearby places(bar+restaurant).I have some Lat Long in DB with place id's. I want to fetch only those Lat Long from DB which is close to User Location Lat Long. Can anyone please tell me what will be the query for that.Suppose my DB has 1000 Lat Long with place id's but only 100 of them (Lat and Long) are close to userLocation. So anyone please guide me regarding this. I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have separate attributes for your place Lats and Longs? Or are they stored in one attribute?

If they are separate, and they are defined as numbers, you can use a [Filter Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression). You would probably need to do two queries.

1) Take your user Lat, add and subtract a number to get a range, and then use a filter expression to get results within that range.

2) Take your user Long, add and subtract a number to get a range, and then use a filter expression to get results within that range.

3) Add your results lists together

Comment: thanks for your help and yes they are defined as separate attributes in DB and there datatype is numbers. But can you please tell me the exact query for this as I am very new to AWS Dynamo DB. I will be thankful.

Comment: I will need to see your database schema and know what SDK you are using to provide code.

Comment: just suppose my Table(Venue) has three attributes Lat, Long, Place_id. I just want to fetch  only those Lat Long which is close to user current Lat Long or location. Can you please make a query on the basis of this. I will be very thankful to you.